# What is my error.log telling me?

Tags: logs

I'm currently studying and I have been told to to use Linux and Apache and to check out the error.log files and access.log files through Apache, but I've currently been stuck for a few days trying to figure out what the log files are telling me, so by any chance could anyone help me figure out what these log files tell me?

Access.log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khFqR.jpg
[image: Attached error.log]

Comment: Please do not post pictures - see the PSA in the "Hot Meta Posts" to the right. Instead, copy the text and paste it. Also you'll find this link on the Google: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat

Answer (score 1):

They're not actually errors, they are quite normal 'notices' informing you of when Apache starts/stops.

An actual error will contain:  [:emerg],  [:crit], or  [:error], instead of [:notice].

The first line in your screenshot shows the PID (Process ID) which Apache spawned as: 1649

The next shows the actual command that was executed: /usr/sbin/apache2

The next shows Apache receiving a SIGTERM signal which gracefully tells Apache to stop (you most likely stopped the service).

If you run VirtualHosts, these can also be set up to log information to other log files on a site-by-site basis.

Check in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and look for any files containing `ErrorLog` as this will point to the location that specific VirtualHost is logging to.